# How to programmatically change selected text font/color?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to make a custom Text Editor that can change font and color of specific typed words. How do I change the Font and or Color of text that I highlight over using the cursor?

I haven't tried to do the highlighting portion quite yet. I have tried to get the entire hEdit(HWND) area and change the font, but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
//In my WndProc (Being handled when I click the Format->Color menu item)
HWND hEdit;
hEdit = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT);

DoSelectColor(hEdit);

//In my WndProc (Being handled when I click the Format->Font menu item)
HWND hEdit;
hEdit = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT);

DoSelectFont(hEdit, hFont);

//Selecting Color
void DoSelectColor(HWND hwnd) {
    CHOOSECOLOR cc = {sizeof(CHOOSECOLOR)};
    cc.Flags = CC_RGBINIT | CC_FULLOPEN || CC_ANYCOLOR;
    cc.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    cc.rgbResult = g_rgbBackground;
    cc.lpCustColors = g_rgbCustom;

    if(ChooseColor(&cc)) {
        g_rgbBackground = cc.rgbResult;
    }
}

//Selecting Font
void DoSelectFont(HWND hwnd, HFONT f) {
    CHOOSEFONT cf = {sizeof(CHOOSEFONT)};
    LOGFONT lf;

    GetObject(f, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf);

    cf.Flags = CF_EFFECTS | CF_INITTOLOGFONTSTRUCT | CF_SCREENFONTS;
    cf.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    cf.lpLogFont = &lf;

    if(ChooseFont(&cf)) {
        HFONT hf = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
        if(hf) {
            f = hf;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like for the hEdit area to change, but I'm quite new to C/C++ and can't seem to figure out why it isn't changing the color of the hEdit area.

Comment: It sounds like this code is running, but you're returning a value from a function whose return type is `void`, so I don't see why it would run at all.

Comment: The return was actually for when I changed the VOID to HFONT. I just forgot to get rid of the return when the way I tried didn't work so I changed it back to void.

Comment: The documentation may help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlgbox/using-common-dialog-boxes There are some examples.

Comment: Nothing in this code changes a color/font of hEdit. And for multi-color control;, use a RichEdit (EM_SETCHARFORMAT)

Comment: A standard edit control does not support formatting other than setting a single color, background color, and font for the entire content. It doesn't support formatting portions of its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the positive commentary.Your not going to be able to do that directly with a `Edit Control`. What you want to use instead is a `Richedit Control`. What you'll probably want to do is first call `SendMessage(hWndRichEdit, EM_SETEDITSTYLE, SES_EMULATESYSEDIT, SES_EMULATESYSEDIT)`; in your `WM_CREATE` handler after you create the `Richedit Control` and then to append text of any style use: `SETTEXTEX stex = { ST_SELECTION, CP_ACP }`; `SendMessage(hWndRichEdit, EM_SETTEXTEX, &stex, (LPARAM)"{\rtf1 Inserting {\b bold} text. \par }")`;

Here's a few links that should help you.

You want to use version 2 or 3 of the `Richedit Control`.

Don't just go copying and pasting code. Read these pages in full before trying to implement them.

MSDN: [Rich Edit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/rich-edit-controls)

MSDN: [About Rich Edit Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/about-rich-edit-controls)

MSDN: [Using Rich Edit Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/using-rich-edit-controls)

Wikipedia: [Rich Text Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)